# A network flow problem need a elegant solution(python)

Tags: python, pandas, list, networkx

I am using a networkx package from python and I have a dataframe

(Sample dataframe)

```
from    to     count
v0      v1     0.1
v0      v2     0.15
v0      v3     0.15
v0      v4     0.25
v0      v5     0.15
and so on..
```

Sample picture(weighted direct graph)

[image]

That is my dataframe.

`{'grad': {0: 'CUHK', 1: 'CUHK', 2: 'CUHK', 3: 'CUHK', 4: 'CUHK', 5: 'CityU', 6: 'CityU', 7: 'CityU', 8: 'CityU', 9: 'HKU', 10: 'HKU', 11: 'HKU', 12: 'HKUST', 13: 'HKUST', 14: 'HKUST', 15: 'HKUST', 16: 'HKUST', 17: 'HKUST', 18: 'Low Frequency', 19: 'Low Frequency', 20: 'Low Frequency', 21: 'Low Frequency', 22: 'Low Frequency', 23: 'Low Frequency', 24: 'PolyU', 25: 'PolyU', 26: 'PolyU', 27: 'PolyU'}, 'to': {0: 'CUHK', 1: 'CityU', 2: 'HKU', 3: 'LingU', 4: 'PolyU', 5: 'CityU', 6: 'HKU', 7: 'LingU', 8: 'PolyU', 9: 'CityU', 10: 'HKU', 11: 'PolyU', 12: 'CUHK', 13: 'CityU', 14: 'HKU', 15: 'HKUST', 16: 'LingU', 17: 'PolyU', 18: 'CUHK', 19: 'CityU', 20: 'HKU', 21: 'HKUST', 22: 'LingU', 23: 'PolyU', 24: 'CityU', 25: 'HKU', 26: 'LingU', 27: 'PolyU'}, 'count': {0: 9, 1: 5, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 3, 9: 3, 10: 9, 11: 4, 12: 2, 13: 1, 14: 2, 15: 1, 16: 4, 17: 4, 18: 49, 19: 34, 20: 29, 21: 34, 22: 3, 23: 36, 24: 1, 25: 1, 26: 1, 27: 11}}`

The principle of ranking is when Vx -> Vy is bigger than Vy -> Vx, Vx has a higher rank than Vy.

e.g. V0 -> V5 = 0.2 and V5 -> V0 = 0.5 so, V5 have a higher rank

Now I am using the brute force method, which loops and checks all the relationships. When the condition is met, I change their order in a new list. -> {V0,V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7}

I want an elegant solution to rank these nodes. Maybe I can get some partial orders like V5>V0 and V0>V1 and use them to form a global order V5>V0>V1, but I don't know how to achieve it. Is there **any** method better than brute force? Is this related to any famous problem?

Comment: My first thought is to sort the count column descending, then keep the first time you see each grad value. so something like `df.sort_values('count', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('grad', keep='first')['grad'].tolist()` but I'm not sure it works as you need. Also in case you have a node like V1 in your picture that does not have an arrow leaving the node, then this one will not be ranked.

Comment: What do you expect as output?

Comment: I expect a list or anything else that concludes a ranking result of grad. e.g. ['HKUST', 'CUHK', 'HKU', 'CityU', 'PolyU', 'LingU']. The list[0] represent the highest rank, this result is generated by my brute force method.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be the following:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

data = {'grad': {0: 'CUHK', 1: 'CUHK', 2: 'CUHK', 3: 'CUHK', 4: 'CUHK', 5: 'CityU', 6: 'CityU', 7: 'CityU', 8: 'CityU', 9: 'HKU', 10: 'HKU', 11: 'HKU', 12: 'HKUST', 13: 'HKUST', 14: 'HKUST', 15: 'HKUST', 16: 'HKUST', 17: 'HKUST', 18: 'Low Frequency', 19: 'Low Frequency', 20: 'Low Frequency', 21: 'Low Frequency', 22: 'Low Frequency', 23: 'Low Frequency', 24: 'PolyU', 25: 'PolyU', 26: 'PolyU', 27: 'PolyU'}, 
          'to': {0: 'CUHK', 1: 'CityU', 2: 'HKU', 3: 'LingU', 4: 'PolyU', 5: 'CityU', 6: 'HKU', 7: 'LingU', 8: 'PolyU', 9: 'CityU', 10: 'HKU', 11: 'PolyU', 12: 'CUHK', 13: 'CityU', 14: 'HKU', 15: 'HKUST', 16: 'LingU', 17: 'PolyU', 18: 'CUHK', 19: 'CityU', 20: 'HKU', 21: 'HKUST', 22: 'LingU', 23: 'PolyU', 24: 'CityU', 25: 'HKU', 26: 'LingU', 27: 'PolyU'}, 
          'count': {0: 9, 1: 5, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 3, 9: 3, 10: 9, 11: 4, 12: 2, 13: 1, 14: 2, 15: 1, 16: 4, 17: 4, 18: 49, 19: 34, 20: 29, 21: 34, 22: 3, 23: 36, 24: 1, 25: 1, 26: 1, 27: 11}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'grad', 'to', edge_attr='count', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
pagerank = nx.pagerank(G, weight='count')
sorted_pagerank = sorted(pagerank.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

This returns a list of tuples with the node and its PageRank score, sorted in descending order of the PageRank score.

```
[('PolyU', 0.4113039270586079),
 ('HKU', 0.1945013448661985),
 ('CityU', 0.14888513201115303),
 ('LingU', 0.09978025157613143),
 ('CUHK', 0.07069262490080512),
 ('HKUST', 0.041291981078138223),
 ('Low Frequency', 0.03354473850896578)]
```

If you want this with the graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'grad', 'to', edge_attr='count', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
pagerank = nx.pagerank(G, weight='count')
sorted_pagerank = sorted(pagerank.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_color='skyblue', node_size=[v * 100 for v in pagerank.values()])
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'count')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]